# PHP - sort array by month and year

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

This is my array:

```
$ar = array( 
 'Jan-2016' => 1,
 'Feb-2016' => 2,
 'Mar-2016' => 3,  
 'Apr-2016' => 4,
 'May-2016' => 4,
 'Jun-2016' => 4,
 'Jul-2016' => 4,
 'Aug-2016' => 4,
 'Sep-2016' => 4,
 'Oct-2016' => 4,
 'Nov-2016' => 4,
 'Dec-2016' => 4,
 'Jan-2015' => 1,
 'Mar-2015' => 1);
```

I want to sort this array by month & year. I've tried below code:

```
ksort($ar);
```

But i can't get result as i expected.

I need result as below array:

```
$ar = array(
 'Jan-2015' => 1,
 'Mar-2015' => 1,
 'Jan-2016' => 1,
 'Feb-2016' => 2,
 'Mar-2016' => 3,  
 'Apr-2016' => 4,
 'May-2016' => 4,
 'Jun-2016' => 4,
 'Jul-2016' => 4,
 'Aug-2016' => 4,
 'Sep-2016' => 4,
 'Oct-2016' => 4,
 'Nov-2016' => 4,
 'Dec-2016' => 4);
```

Comment: `uksort` is your option

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php - Sort an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function.

Comment: Can u provide code this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`uksort` is the right function to use :

```
uksort($ar, function($a1, $a2) {
        $time1 = strtotime($a1);
        $time2 = strtotime($a2);

        return $time1 - $time2;
    });

print_r($ar);
```

Comment: `return $time1 - $time2` is much simpler.

Comment: @u_mulder well doesn't change much, but you're right

Answer (score 0):

Supplement: Sort Order

```
$sortOrder = true;  // ASC
$sortOrder = false; // DESC

uksort($array, function($a, $b) use($sortOrder) {
    $timeA = strtotime($a);
    $timeB = strtotime($b);

    return $sortOrder ? ($timeA - $timeB) : ($timeB - $timeA);
});
```